# Google Sheet Appscript Changelog to Track Deleted Row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a changelog in my spreadsheet to keep track of information that is added, edited, or removed. The issue is that the changelog cannot detect if a user "[Delete row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95H3V.png)". Is it even possible to have the changelog track deleted row or am I out of luck? Thanks .

```
function onEdit(e){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetNameTracker = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
    if (sheetNameTracker !== "Changelog") {
        let sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Changelog');
        var range = e.range.getA1Notation();
        var user = e.user.getUsername();  
        var function_source = "onEdit";
        var time = new Date();
        var changeType = 'EDIT';
        console.log(user);
        var oldValue = e.oldValue;
        var newValue = e.value;
        var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
        sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,1,8).setValues([[time.toLocaleString(),function_source,changeType,sheetNameTracker,range,user,oldValue,newValue]]);
    } 
}
```

[Example Google Sheet with Appscript](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xwxqklSUn5IUT90SV8TZ7f6LdQMq2N3ZvjeDShU5RhY/edit#gid=1117370704)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Is it even possible to have the changelog track deleted row or am I out of luck?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I am asking if there is a way I can have changelog track deleted row. Or is it not possible?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `I am asking if there is a way I can have changelog track deleted row. Or is it not possible?`, in the current stage, the event object of the OnEdit trigger doesn't include the property of `changeType`. So, in this case, it is required to use the installable OnChangge trigger. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

After you copy and paste the following modified script, [please install OnChange trigger to the function `onChange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). By this, when a row is removed, the value of `REMOVE_ROW` is returned as `e.changeType`.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetNameTracker = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  if (sheetNameTracker !== "Changelog") {
    let sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Changelog');
    var range = e.range && e.range.getA1Notation(); // Modified
    var user = e.user.getUsername();
    var function_source = "onEdit";
    var time = new Date();
    var changeType = e.changeType || 'EDIT'; // Modified
    console.log(user);
    var oldValue = e.oldValue;
    var newValue = e.value;
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, 8).setValues([
      [time.toLocaleString(), function_source, changeType, sheetNameTracker, range, user, oldValue, newValue]
    ]);
  }
}

// Please install OnChange trigger to this function.
function onChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType == "EDIT") return;
  onEdit(e);
}
```

- In this modified script, when a row is removed, `onChange` is automatically run by the installable onChange trigger. And, the event object is sent to `onEdit`, and the log is recorded by your script.

#### Note:

- In the case of the OnEdit trigger, even when a row is deleted, this trigger is not fired while the trigger is fired when a cell is edited. On the other hand, in the case of the installable OnChange trigger, the trigger is fired for both the editing cell and removing a row. In this modification, this situation is used.
- In the case of OnChange trigger, in the current stage, the event object of OnChange trigger doesn't include `range` object. By this, the removed row is not known while it can be found that a row is removed. If you want to know the removed row, as a workaround, it is required to compare the old sheet and the new sheet before and after the edit. I'm worried that in this case, the script might be complicated. So, in this answer, I proposed a simple modification.

Comment: Thanks, I tested the script and it works! My only question I have is that I want to know what information was removed from the deleted row. Is it an easy fix to the script to know what info was removed? 

Comment: @Kay Thank you for replying. From `Thanks, I tested the script and it works!`, I understood that your issue was resolved. About `My only question I have is that I want to know what information was removed from the deleted row. Is it an easy fix to the script to know what info was removed?`, I have already mentioned this in my answer. If your this request is achieved, the script becomes comprecate. If you want the answer, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Kay About your new question of `My only question I have is that I want to know what information was removed from the deleted row. Is it an easy fix to the script to know what info was removed?`, in this case, as a simple way, how about checking the row numbers by adding a template column including the row numbers? By this, when a row is removed, it can be found from the removed row number. But, I cannot know your actual expected result from your reply, if this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will use that. I did see one bug. Sometimes when I delete, the changelog will track it as "EDIT" but then "FORMAT" will overwrite it. In the video, you can see I typed "b" and deleted "b", but it doesn't show up in the changelog. I tried using Utilities.sleep(1000); but it did not work. Do you happen to have any idea? Video Proof: https://youtu.be/JsyslZnxPzs

Comment: I think I fixed my issue! https://pastebin.com/KDTD20Tw

Comment: @Kay Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot understand your current situation. Your issues were resolved. Is my understanding correct? Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation?

Comment: There was 1 bug with your script. The bug was sometimes a function was called twice which was the reason why the changelog was overwriting information. I fixed the bug on line 25 (https://pastebin.com/KDTD20Tw).  You can see the bug here: youtu.be/JsyslZnxPzs

Comment: @Kay Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation. 1. What is `changelog_script`? You don't want to use the OnEdit trigger? 2. I cannot replicate your situation. Can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current situation? By this, I would like to confirm it. It seems that you have changed my proposed script. By this, I cannot understand your current situation. I apologize that you changed my proposed script.

Comment: @Kay Although unfortunately, I cannot still understand `changelog_script`, for example, in your situation, it seems that you want to detect removing row. In this case, how about replacing `changelog_script(e);` to `if (e.changeType == "REMOVE_ROW") changelog_script(e);`? By this, only when the row is removed, `changelog_script(e)` is run. How about this?

Comment: @Kay And, although I'm not sure about your actual situation from your question and reply, in your situation, if multiple users use the spreadsheet,LockService might be also useful. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock) But, now, I'm required to correctly know your current situation. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad.